# I can't publish a ASP.NET project, even though I can build it

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, web-deployment

Some time ago I was working pretty fine publishing an ASP.NET project using a publish profile (.pubxml), suddenly after doing a minor change in the .pubxml I get more than 1000 error messages, even though I can build and run the project locally.

This is the .pubxml

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<!--
This file is used by the publish/package process of your Web project. You can customize the behavior of this process
by editing this MSBuild file. In order to learn more about this please visit https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=208121. 
-->
<Project ToolsVersion="4.0" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
   <ItemGroup>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder">
      <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>Temp</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder">
      <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>Uploads</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
     
    <!--<Content Update="TempImages/**" CopyToPublishDirectory="Never" />-->

    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFolder">
      <ObjectName>dirPath</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>TempImages</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFile">
      <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>Web.config</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
    <MsDeploySkipRules Include="CustomSkipFile">
      <ObjectName>filePath</ObjectName>
      <AbsolutePath>ConfigConn.xml</AbsolutePath>
    </MsDeploySkipRules>
  </ItemGroup>
  <PropertyGroup>
    <WebPublishMethod>FileSystem</WebPublishMethod>
    <LastUsedBuildConfiguration>Release</LastUsedBuildConfiguration>
    <LastUsedPlatform>Any CPU</LastUsedPlatform>
    <SiteUrlToLaunchAfterPublish />
    <LaunchSiteAfterPublish>True</LaunchSiteAfterPublish>
    <PrecompileBeforePublish>True</PrecompileBeforePublish>
    <EnableUpdateable>True</EnableUpdateable>
    <DebugSymbols>False</DebugSymbols>
    <WDPMergeOption>MergeAllPagesAndControlToASingleAssembly</WDPMergeOption>
    <UseMerge>True</UseMerge>
    <ContentAssemblyName>EspiaWeb_deploy</ContentAssemblyName>
    <ExcludeApp_Data>True</ExcludeApp_Data>
    <!--<ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>Web.config;ConfigConn.xml</ExcludeFilesFromDeployment>-->
    <ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>.vs</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>
    <!--<ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>.vs;Temp;Uploads;TempImages</ExcludeFoldersFromDeployment>-->
    <publishUrl>W:\Documentos\espiaupd</publishUrl>
    <DeleteExistingFiles>False</DeleteExistingFiles>
  </PropertyGroup>
</Project>
```

These are just 5 out of +1000 error messages I get

```
LogInExterno\Web References\ReferenciaUsuario\Reference.cs(742,153): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ResponseNamespace' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [W:\Axon\Proyectos\espiaWeb\espiaWeb\espiaWeb.csproj]
LogInExterno\Web References\ReferenciaUsuario\Reference.cs(742,196): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'Use' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [W:\Axon\Proyectos\espiaWeb\espiaWeb\espiaWeb.csproj]
LogInExterno\Web References\ReferenciaUsuario\Reference.cs(742,200): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [W:\Axon\Proyectos\espiaWeb\espiaWeb\espiaWeb.csproj]
LogInExterno\Web References\ReferenciaUsuario\Reference.cs(742,256): error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'ParameterStyle' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?) [W:\Axon\Proyectos\espiaWeb\espiaWeb\espiaWeb.csproj]
LogInExterno\Web References\ReferenciaUsuario\Reference.cs(742,271): error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'Services' does not exist in the namespace 'System.Web' (are you missing an assembly reference?) [W:\Axon\Proyectos\espiaWeb\espiaWeb\espiaWeb.csproj]
```

Comment: I've never knew why all these exception were thrown, anyways, thankfully is 2023 now and this was solved with newer technology. (new OS, new .NET Framework, new Visual Studio)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you right click the project and go to Publish, you should be able to create a new Publish profile. Also you should be able to view the old publish profile in the GUI. Try copying over the values from the old one to a new one?

Comment: I tried with differnt publish profiles, now when I right click the project and click Publish, nothing happens!!... so I even tried the following from command line:

    dotnet publish .\espiaWeb.csproj /p:PublishProfile=App_Data\PublishProfiles\prueba.pubxml

And, still I get the error messages

Comment: What error message? Can you post some screenshots of what is happening. If nothing at all opens when you right click and go to publish that sounds like Visual Studio might be corrupted.

Comment: The +1000 error messages I described in the question

Comment: I've never knew why all these exception were thrown, anyways, thankfully is 2023 now and this was solved with newer technology. (new OS, new .NET Framework, new Visual Studio)